# Array values in SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(
        '',
        '$form['name']',
        '$form['saddress']',
        '$form['apt']',
        '$form['zip']',
        '$form['homephone']',
        '$form['cellphone']',
        '$form['email']',
        '$form['    ']',
        '$form['city']',
        '$form['state']',
        '$form['country']',
        '$salt','$hash',
        '$form['username']'
    )");
```

How would I make that work? It's giving me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

Comment: don't forget the dots ... ' . $form['city'] . '

Comment: Why are dots necessary? I've never used them before when inserting normal variables into a SQL query.

Comment: or {} '{$form['name']}',

Comment: you can use the dots of curly brace. I prefer the dots since it's easier to read. see Nexerus or rfausak answer and see what you prefer.

Comment: funny i prefer the {} for the same reason!

Comment: I hope you never have any users from [O'Fallen, IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Fallon,_Illinois) or Ireland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using curly brackets around the variables, like this:

```
..
'{$form['name']}',
'{$form['saddress']}',
..
```

Answer (score 1):

Either by removing the single quotes from the `$form['x']` or by doing something like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO x VALUES(
  '" . mysql_real_escape_string($form['x']) . "',
  '" . mysql_real_escape_string($form['x']) . "'
");
```

Notice that there are double quotes inside the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem that stems from PHP's ability to parse strings for variables, which can get confusing.  I prefer to keep my variables outside of the strings, and concatenate when needed.

Here's what I would do:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('" .
    implode("','", array(
        "",
        $form['name'],
        $form['saddress'],
        $form['apt'],
        $form['zip'],
        $form['homephone'],
        $form['cellphone'],
        $form['email'],
        $form['    '],
        $form['city'],
        $form['state'],
        $form['country'],
        $salt,
        $hash,
        $form['username']
    )) . "')";
);
```